# height auto vs height 100%，under a fit-content container

Tags: html, css, height

I make a simple html as

```
<div style="height: fit-content; display: flex">
    <div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; border: black solid 2px"></div>
    <div style="height: auto; width: 500px; border: red solid 2px"></div>
</div>
```

Basically, I want the page has two containers, one by left and one by right. The left container has some height (it maybe changed by js, but I just put a fix height here), the parent container fit the height of the left container, and the right container take the height of the parent container.

I found that for the right container, if I put the height as `100%`, it won't match the height of the left container. Instead, the height will collapse. But if I put height as `auto` as the sample code, everything is fine.

Why the browser has a behaviour like this? What is the `auto` mean here? many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "auto" value means that the `stretch` value of `align-items` has an effect.

From [CSS Level 1 Flexbox - 9.4. Cross Size Determination - step 11](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#algo-stretch)

> Determine the used cross size of each flex item. **If a flex item has align-self: stretch, its computed cross size property is auto**, and neither of its cross-axis margins are auto, the used outer cross size is the used cross size of its flex line, clamped according to the item’s used min and max cross sizes. Otherwise, the used cross size is the item’s hypothetical cross size.

`stretch` is the default value of `align-items` and is in play in your example. Any other value of height will not cause the item's cross size to stretch.

100% then is a percentage of an non-definite height and computes to 0.